# One week imposible to Deploy django in windows with apache

Tags: django, windows, apache, deployment

500 Internal Server Error is what I have all the time.

Hello guys
I’m trying to deploy django with apache server in Windows Without any success, 
Any help is welcome.

pro1.local is already setup in host and Works fine.

WSGI is perfectly installed.

mod_wsgi-express module-config

```
LoadFile "c:/program files (x86)/python37-32/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/program files (x86)/python37-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/program files (x86)/python37-32"
```

Httpd.conf

```
LoadFile "c:/program files (x86)/python37-32/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/program files (x86)/python37-32/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/program files (x86)/python37-32"
```

Httpd-vhost.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>


    ServerName pro1.local
    ErrorLog "logs/pro1.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/pro1.local-access.log" common

    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\pro1\proyecto\proyecto\wsgi.py"

    <Directory "C:\pro1\proyecto\proyecto">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>    


</VirtualHost>
```

log

```
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:49.295821 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50643] mod_wsgi (pid=6720): Target WSGI script 'C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:49.295821 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50643] mod_wsgi (pid=6720): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:49.311446 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50643] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:49.311446 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50643]   File "C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:49.311446 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50643]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:49.311446 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50643] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'\r
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:51.134820 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1136] [client 127.0.0.1:50642] mod_wsgi (pid=6720): Target WSGI script 'C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:51.134820 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1136] [client 127.0.0.1:50642] mod_wsgi (pid=6720): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py'., referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:51.135822 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1136] [client 127.0.0.1:50642] Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:51.135822 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1136] [client 127.0.0.1:50642]   File "C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r, referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:51.135822 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1136] [client 127.0.0.1:50642]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r, referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:51.135822 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1136] [client 127.0.0.1:50642] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'\r, referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:58.760191 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50644] mod_wsgi (pid=6720): Target WSGI script 'C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:58.760191 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50644] mod_wsgi (pid=6720): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py'., referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:58.760191 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50644] Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:58.761190 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50644]   File "C:/pro1/proyecto/proyecto/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r, referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:58.761190 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50644]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r, referer: http://pro1.local/
[Mon Aug 05 10:26:58.761190 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 1132] [client 127.0.0.1:50644] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'\r, referer: http://pro1.local/
```

What am I doing bad?

Comment: Set env variable for `PYTHONPATH` so it will include where you have your libs (including django), or use `WSGIPythonPath`

Comment: If I add apache does not start with this: WSGIPythonPath "C:\pro1\proyecto;C:\pro1\Lib\site-packages"